# getting Not paid members

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, where-clause

I have a member table

```
 member_Id
 member_Firstname
```

another table  Paymentschedules

```
  paymentschedule_Id
  member_Id
  paymentschedule_amountdue values(100 rs,200rs)
  paymentschedule_amonutpaid values (30 rs,40 rs)
  paymentschedule_ActualDatetobepaid  values(2011-02-03,2011-02-01,2011-03-01)
  paymentschedule_ datepaid  values like(2011-09-12,2011-08-10,2011-11-12,2010-08-01)
```

My problem is can i get the members firstname who are overdue upto "today"  taking into account these values "ActualDatetobepaid" and "amonutpaid " and "amountdue"   and "datepaid"

Can any one help on this one

Comment: small question, 30 and 40 (paymentschedule_amountdue) is the amount that needed to be paid?

Comment: @ Eddsstudio sorry for confusing u i have edited the question and i want the memberdetails who has due like this condition(overdue < 7 days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last request, "Add 7 days", is solved by adding 7 days to J0HN's solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT member_Firstname  
FROM member m 
  JOIN Paymentscedules p ON p.member_id = m.member_id 
WHERE DATE_ADD(paymentschedule_ActualDatetobepaid, INTERVAL 7 DAY)< NOW() 
  AND paymentschedule_amountdue > paymentschedule_amonutpaid
```

Comment: Hi I am using mysql work bench it was giving error at this place INTERVAL 7 DAY)

Comment: Maybe just need to encapse 7 DAY in quotes, it depends on the DB you use, like this: INTREVAL '7 DAY'

Comment: @and i want the memberdetails between 8 to 30 days(taking into acccount today like this today is (08.08.2011) i want the details members details between these dates (16.08.2011 to 08.09.2011)  would you pls help me

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand columns' meanings, but try this:

```
select distinct member_Firstname 
from member m
join Paymentscedules p on p.member_id = m.member_id
where paymentschedule_ActualDatetobepaid<now() and paymentschedule_amountdue > paymentschedule_amonutpaid
```

If you could provide data types user for that columns and column meanings I could come up with more precise solution.

Comment: john i edited the question i have place wrong values pls take a look and i want members those are overdue from today date to (Add 7 days)

Comment: date due is today suppose (08-08-2011) i want the members those who have not paid upto (15-08-2011) this date ..can i get that like this condition..